# OpenSearch - Complex conditions and child documents query

Tags: opensearch

I need to have a complex query like this one:

```
POST books/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(tag:'1' AND author:('A' OR 'B')) OR (tag:'2' AND author:('A' OR 'C'))"
    }
  }
}
```

...but also be able to query an array of nested documents at the same time, somewhat like this:

```
POST books/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(tag:'1' AND author:('A' OR 'B')) OR (tag:'2' AND author:('A' OR 'C')) OR references[*].bookId: 7 OR references[*].publisher: 'weird press'"
    }
  }
}
```

Where `references` is an array on the main document, that contains other documents.

Notice the part `OR references[*].bookId: 7 OR references[*].publisher: 'weird press'`, where I try to find the books that contain references to another book with ID 7 or references to books published by `weird press`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you can simply do this:

```
POST books/_search
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "(tag:'1' AND author:('A' OR 'B')) OR (tag:'2' AND author:('A' OR 'C')) OR references.bookId: 7 OR references.publisher: 'weird press'"
    }
  }
}
```

At least, it seems to be working for me, despite the fact that I cannot find ANYTHING about it in the documentation... Not to mention that it is not so intuitive...

If anyone knows where this is documented, let me know.