# Can I use OpenSearch.Client to build a "query string" query?

Tags: c#, opensearch

I am using the [`OpenSearch.Client`](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/clients/OSC-dot-net/) to access an OpenSearch node.

I have seen examples of using C# expressions to build various OpenSearch queries, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75484479/2173353). This seems helpful enough, to avoid building the query yourself 100% manually.

But in my case, I want to use a [query string](https://opensearch.org/docs/latest/search-plugins/sql/full-text/#query-string) that will contain much nested AND/OR logic ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77088405/2173353) is what my query might look like, in case you are interested). And I see that the single method for issuing such a query string accepts a string argument for the query:

```
openSearchClient
    .Search<Document>(s => s
        .Index("documents")
        .QueryOnQueryString(queryonquerystring: "...")
    );
```

Is there a way to build this `queryonquerystring` string query using C# expressions code?

Does `OpenSearch.Client` support it or I will have to use another library (maybe `Lucene.NET`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if using `Lucene.NET` could build such a query, but it turns out that using the `OpenSearch.Client` way of making queries works much better:

```
var response = openSearchClient.Search<Document>(s => s
            .Index(documentsIndexName)
            .Query(q => q
                .Bool(bq => bq
                    .Must(mq =>
                    {
                         return mq.Term(d => d.field1, 0) && (!mq.Term(d => d.field2, 3) || mq.Term(d => d.field3, 7));
                    });
```